Can't redirect correctly after login with Auth0 on an Ionic React App?
I'm working on an Ionic App with React. Im using Auth0 for user authentication. Everything is working on localhost web, I can login and the app is returning to /callback after login.
Then, when I compiled and build the apk and install on my Android device I have this problem that after a successfull login, the universal login from auth0 closes, but instead of redirect me to /callback seems to go back to '/' without authenticate the current user.
index.tsx

import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from "./serviceWorkerRegistration";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { domain as auth0Domain, clientId, callbackUri } from "./auth.config";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={auth0Domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: callbackUri
      }}
      // For using Auth0-React with Ionic on Android and iOS,
      // it's important to use refresh tokens without the fallback
      useRefreshTokens={true}
      useRefreshTokensFallback={false}
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

< App />
const App: React.FC = () => {
   const { handleRedirectCallback } = useAuth0();
   const history = useHistory()

   useEffect(() => {
      CapApp.addListener("appUrlOpen", async ({ url }) => {
         if (url.startsWith(callbackUri)) {
            if (
               url.includes("state") &&
               (url.includes("code") || url.includes("error"))
            ) {
               await handleRedirectCallback(url);
            }
            await Browser.close();
         }
      });
   }, [handleRedirectCallback, history]);

   return (
      <IonApp>
         <IonReactRouter>
            <AppRoutes />
         </IonReactRouter>
      </IonApp>
   );
};

< AppRoutes />
export default function AppRoutes() {
   const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()

   return (
      <IonRouterOutlet>
         < Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => isAuthenticated
            ? <Redirect
               from="/"
               to='/callback'
            />
            : <Login />
         }
         />
         < Route exact={true} path="/callback" render={() => <Callback />} />

         < CampusRoutes />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
   )
}

capacitor.config.ts
import { CapacitorConfig } from "@capacitor/cli";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: "app.id.name",
  appName: "Forvet Campus",
  webDir: "build",
  plugins: {
    CapacitorAuth0Plugin: {
      clientId: 'true_client_id',
      domain: 'true_domain',
      scheme: 'app.id.name',
      redirectUri: 'app.id.name://true_domain/capacitor/app.id.name/callback',
    },
  },
};

export default config;

< LoginButton />
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { Browser } from "@capacitor/browser";
import { IonButton } from "@ionic/react";

const LoginButton: React.FC = () => {
   const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

   const login = async () => {
      await loginWithRedirect({
         async openUrl(url) {
            await Browser.open({
               url,
               windowName: "_self"
            });
         }
      });
   };

   return <IonButton color='secondary' onClick={login}>Ingresar</IonButton>;
};

export default LoginButton;


Callback URLs and logout on Auth0 are set correctly
I also add on AndroidManifest.xml <intent-filter> with attribute 

Good question. I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?
